# Manually edit chapter for one page with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\listoftables
\clearpage

\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
```

My list of symbols is already two pages long. The problem: on the second page header it does not say "List of Symbols" but "List of Tables". If I use `\chapter` instead of `\chapter*` the chapter will be numbered eventhough it shouldn't be numbered. Any ideas on how to manually change the "current chapter" for `fancyhdr` on this single page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise against using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) with the [`memoir` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), as the class already provides a similar functionality to updating the headers/footers.

In order to obtain the appropriate header for your List of Symbols, use

```
\chapter*[List of Symbols]{List of Symbols}
```

The optional argument for `\chapter` also changes the header (or chapter mark).

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm writing a thesis and, for some reason, i chose the memoir class. However, with my current code the report class produces too many errors so I will stick with the memoir. For the PhD thesis I will probably switch then.

Comment: @Relam: Yes, your minimal code shows you're using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir), so I provided a solution based on that. The default `report` class does not offer the option of using a `\chapter*` with an optional argument. You can only use `\chapter[..]{...}` or `\chapter*{...}`, but not `\chapter*[..]{...}`.